# I am hungry. >> Latin

Tags: english

How can I say "I am hungry." in Latin? Suggestions:

1. Sum esuriens.
2. Habeo fames.
3. Habeo inedia.
4. Esurio.

And what about "I am thirsty."?

Context: I study alone Latin.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, it's very good that you have come up with several possible translations. What would be even better is if you could add your thoughts to those translations: how do you feel about them, or what are you uncertain about?

Comment: In some languages people say "I am hungry." while in some other ones people say "I have hunger.". In Latin there is even a verb - in sentence 4).

Answer (score 4):

You can probably find various ways to express your degree of hunger using *fames*; for example, you could say *fame laboro* (I am suffering from hunger), but that seems rather dramatic. Your suggestions *habeo fames* and *habeo inedia* are grammatically wrong; it should be the accusative *famem/inediam*. And *inedia* does not mean "hunger," but "fasting," so it seems not very fitting. In any event, both expressions do not seem idiomatic to me.

For simply saying "I'm hungry," *esurio* seems the most straightforward way.

See for example this dialogue (from Plautus: [*Casina*, 3,6](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/plautus/cas.shtml)):

> Ly. Quid fit?
> Ol. Tu amas; ego esurio et sitio.
>
> Ly. What's up?
> Ol. You are in love; I am hungry and thirsty.

Which also answers the question how to say "I'm thirsty." But remember: *Qui amat, tamen hercle si esurit, nullum esurit* (he who loves, by God, he won't go hungry, even if he's hungry).